# script16389: unspecified error. polyfill (1,10884)

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I have a JSP page initially rendered correctly and when I click on a link, the page will refresh and the following error is coming in Windows 10, Edge 42. I am not sure on the error and I didn't used any polyfill. When I click on the error, it is not showing the exact error line to debug. Please find below the JS code and help.

> script16389: unspecified error. polyfill (1,10884)

**main.js**

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    var el = e.target;
    var className = el.className;
    if (className.indexOf("dropdown-section") < 0 && className.indexOf("dropdown-content") < 0 && className !== "dropdown-selected" && !(el.tagName === "INPUT" && $(el).parent().hasClass("dropdown-container"))) {
        $(".dropdown-section").removeClass("open");
    }
});

function buildShortAnswer(rq) {
    return "<input type=\"text\" class=\"input_box\" id=\"question" + rq.questionId + "\" tabindex=\"" + (rq.questionSettings.index + 3) + "\" name=\"question" + rq.questionId + "\" onkeyup=\"handleShortAnswerChange(event, " + rq.questionId + ")\" maxlength=\"" + rq.questionProperties[SHORT_ANSWER].maxLength + "\" />";
}

function replaceTag(tag) {
    var tagsToReplace = {
        '&': '&amp;',
        '<': '&lt;',
        '>': '&gt;'
//      '"': '&quot;'
    };
    return tagsToReplace[tag] || tag;
}

function safeTagsReplace(str) {
    return str.replace(/[&<>]/g, replaceTag);
}

function isValidUserName(username) {
    var regex = /^(?!.*[&<>]).*$/;
    if (regex.test(username)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;  
}

function isValidemail(email) {
    var regex = /^([^\s@<>]{1,200})@([^\s@<>]{1,300})$/;
    if (regex.test(email.trim())) {  
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url){
        url = window.location.href;
    }
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results){
        return null;
    }
    if (!results[2]){
        return '';
    }
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Comment: One of the polyfills you're using has an error. That's all the help we can offer you without seeing any of the relevant code.

Comment: I didn't used any polyfill. I have read in a post where backslashes in Edge behave differently and may cause this issue. Do you have any idea on it?

Comment: I don't know if this works in Edge, but in most good browsers you can double click the error in the console and it will take you to the line which threw the error, and show you the stack state as well. That would be helpful debugging information

Comment: It is not taking me to the line. Please find my updated post and let me know if you can help

Comment: This error can occur in Edge on a page with no polyfills, no jQuery or any other JS libraries, if the page has a form. Clicking on the error takes you to a blank line in the debugger. I thought Edge was a good browser... but suddenly I have doubts.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, that is an issue conflicting with the AutoFormFill incorporated extension of edge. You can disable the feature selecting Settings, scrolling down and clicking "View advanced settings" and under Autofill section disabling the switch "Save form entries". Apart from the error, it shouldn´t affect your program´s execution.

Comment: Thanks, This helps, To Asker @Abraham Gnanasingh Please accept it as correct answer